# MySQL query to select distinct values from one table and all values from a separate table

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables for surveys. Table 1 contains the surveys that are sent out with the following fields: SID,SalesRep,Location. Table 2 contains the survey results that are returned with the following fields: RID,SID,QID,AID.

In table 1, SID is unique, and there are no duplicates. In Table 2, RID is unique, and represents each question that is answered, and the answer. The SID in Table 2 represents the survey from which the questions have been answered. So, if there were 10 questions answered on the survey, there would be 10 rows in Table 2 with the same SID.

What I need to do is find out how many surveys have been sent and how many taken for each sales person. I can use two queries to find the information separately:

1. SELECT * FROM Table1
2. SELECT DISTINCT Table2.SID, Table1.SalesRep,Table1.Location FROM Table2 INNER JOIN Table1 on Table1.SID = Table2.SID

What I would like to do is have ONE query that will give me both results. I'm assuming it would take some kind of OUTER JOIN since there will be more results from Table1 than Table2 because we don't get 100% return on the surveys. However, when I try to run an OUTER JOIN, it locks up and returns nothing. These tables aren't very large at this point.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Is this even possible?

Comment: give some data and expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have't specified well enough about your result but as I could understand,You may try this hope it works
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE SID IN (SELECT DISTINCT SID FROM Table2)

If it doesn't works please specify well

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think that would only give me one set of results. It would yield a list of surveys sent that had been responded to. The result I'm looking for is to yield results for comparison, so I'll actually need two sets of results, so that I can use them for comparison on a report. For example, the report details will have: Sales Person 1, Location 1, Surveys Sent - 25, Surveys Taken -10 | Sales Person 1, Location 2, Surveys Sent - 15, Surveys Taken 4 | Sales Person 2, Location 2, Surveys Sent - 30, Surveys Taken - 20.

Comment: do you need output to display all the sid that are in table 2 i.e. if an sid appers 4 times in the table the it should be displayed 4 times and along with rest of the sid from table 2 along with all details

Comment: No, I need all sid from Table 1 with accompanying fields (salesperson, location), and Distinct sid from Table 2. End result, I need a count of all sid in table one and a count of distinct sid in Table 2.

Comment: use uninon od both query like        
query1          
UNION        
query2

Comment: The union got me in the right direction, thank you. I ended up doing a union of the two queries and I concatenated a string in the Select statement of each for the SID to distinguish which ones were Sent vs Taken. Example: SELECT CONCAT(COUNT(SID,'S')) AS SID...UNION SELECT CONCAT(COUNT(DISTINCT SID,'T')) AS SID. Worked beautifully!